# Regex match word except when it's a part of a url

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I'm trying to match all occurances of a word... except when they occur within a url, then I don't want to match it.
Lets assume I'm trying to match the word 'co'

```
should match: cots and co 
should not match: not http://me.co.uk
should match: last of my co.
```

I'm trying to do with with a negative look behind, with [something like this](http://regexr.com/396ht):

```
(?!http)\bco\b
```

`\b` makes sure the `co` in `cots` isn't matched but it still matches the `co` in the url.

```
(?!http).*\bco\b // This matches the whole sentence until the url
(?!http.*)\bco\b // this doesn't match anything
```

Not sure if negative look behind is the way to go, in my case, it is safe to assume all url's start with `http://` so that's where I'm trying to start.

So how would I match the `co` everywhere except in url?

edit:

I want to match just the word, not the whole sentence
I'm doing this on c#

edit 2:
What I'm trying to do is convert all non-url keywords to internal urls on my blog.

What I've got now:

```
string orig = "co and http://me.co.uk";
string pros = Regex.Replace(orig, @"https?://\S*?co|\bco\b", m => string.Format("<a href='/co'>co</a>"));
```

<sup>(using the answer below)</sup>

This currently gives me

```
<a href='/co'>co</a> and <a href='/co'>co</a>.uk
```

and What I want is

```
<a href='/co'>co</a> and http://me.co.uk
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to match a word containing the string or a whole line?

Comment: Which language/tool are you using for regex?

Comment: Negative lookbehinds are like this: `(?<! )` You're using a negative lookahead!...

Comment: @Unihedron Ah! I must have misread, will get back with the correction, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this in C#:

```
(?<!https?://\S*)\bco\b
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't match url on online demo you've linked, but, for some reason, on my c# it is matching up. what does the `~` on the demo mean?

Comment: ah, it does seem to be matching the url as well, look at the substitution column here: http://regex101.com/r/dH3rQ0/3

Comment: Amazing, that works, thank you! I was trying with `(?<!https?://).*\bco\b` .. which was selecting everything from beginning.. kind of close, but no cigar!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. Only due to C# regex it allows **variable length lookbehind**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?!http\S+\.co(\.|\?|$)).*\b(co)\b
```

Match is in group 1 - see [demo](http://rubular.com/r/LyzQEbwucb) against these inputs:

```
cots and co 
last of my co.
http://me.co.uk
http://me.example.co
http://me.example.co?foo=bar
```

Comment: Hi, I'm probably missing something, but this cuts off all text left of last match!